# Can Emacs AC mode (autocomplete) mode be configured to ignore numbers?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I frequently include numerical data, phone numbers, etc. when typing text files, and this creates an annoyance with AC mode. Now when I type "2" I get an autocomplete option with every number or numerical code I have ever typed starting with "2". Not very helpful to say the least.

I went in and cleaned out my `ac-comphist.dat`, but it just gets polluted with numbers again. Is there a way to prevent these entries from being added in the first place, perhaps with a regexp filter? I tried setting the variable `ac-ignores` with a list of integers, but it doesn't seem to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I never noticed for decimal numerals, but for hex ones it got really annoying.  I fixed it by redefining `ac-prefix-default` like so:

```
(eval-after-load "auto-complete"
  '(progn
     (defun ac-prefix-default ()
       "Same as `ac-prefix-symbol' but ignore a number prefix."
       (let ((start (ac-prefix-symbol)))
         (when (and start
                  (not (string-match "^\\(?:0[xX][0-9A-Fa-f]+\\|[0-9]+\\)$"
                                     (buffer-substring-no-properties start (point)))))
           start)))
     ))
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you clarify for me where exactly this code should go? And, if necessary, how the regexp may need to be modified so that stings like "12345-678" or "12:34" would also be ignored?

Comment: It would go in your init.el.  I have it wrapped in eval-after-load, and I edited the answer to reflect this.  I try to never modify files that I didn't write, because I have no interest in maintaining patches for them.  auto-complete always seems to get updated when I update my packages.